# Password for ssh@localhost

Tags: ssh

My Ubuntu version is 16.04.

Am getting password prompt for root@localhost during the execution of command "sudo start-dfs.sh" from hduser, it is prompting password for root@localhost so i have given main user password but didn't work.

Then i changed the root password (sudo -i) and again tried to connect the localhost using the below command (from root) with new root password but no luck.
ssh root@localhost

can anyone suggest the solution please?

Answer (score 1):

Check your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file:

**Change from:**

```
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
StrictModes yes
```

**Change to:**

```
PermitRootLogin yes
# StrictModes yes
```

Then restart the `sshd` daemon.

```
$ sudo service sshd restart
```